# Как в JS преобразовать строку с ASCII кодами символов в строку просто символов

Tags: javascript

Строка "3132333441424344" должна быть преобразована в строку "1234ABCD". Спасибо

Comment: Разбить по два символа и применить к ним `String.fromCharCode`

Comment: В ноде можно через `Buffer`

Answer (score 1):

Непосредственно для вашего задания подойдёт такой код

```
const inputString = '3132333441424344';
let newString = '';
for (let i = 0, {length} = inputString; i < length; i += 2) {
  newString += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(inputString.substr(i, 2), 16));
}
```

Результат будет храниться в переменной `newString`

Comment: Чтобы fromCharCode правильно отработала к каждой паре символов нужно обязательно приставить префикс "0x", это я убедился точно, а еще по-моему parseInt здесь лишнее. Завтра проверю. У меня заработало так   function palStr2HexDecoder(input) {
   var output = "",i=0;
   while (input[i*2]&&input[i*2+1]){
    output+= String.fromCharCode("0x"+input.substr(i*2,2)); 
    i++;
   }
   return output;
  }

Comment: Чем обрамлять код чтобы он выглядел здесь как код а не как текст????

Comment: @Павел вот такими символами, как и в сообщении ``

Comment: @Павел, если вы не знали, то `parseInt` имеет два аргумента - значение, которое надо распарить, и СТЕПЕНЬ СЧИСЛЕНИЯ. Зачем дописывать `0х` перед каждым числом, если можно вызвать функцию `parseInt` с вторым параметром равным 16?!

Comment: @NickLaptev спасибо